# Use lodash chain with a promise to synchronize data

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, angular-promise

I'm trying without any success to chain string manipulation using lodash chain and promise. My refColors.length is always 0, I never enter the if statement because the service is being called after the statement is tested.

What I tries to do in my function

```
initiateModalData(refColorList: any) {

    refColorList.forEach((values, index) => {
        const listRefRows: Array<GblRowValues> = [];
        const initialcolors: Array<any> = [];
        const refColors: Array<any> = [];
        const headList: Array<any> = [];
        this.rowId = 1;

         _(value)
                .chain()
                .tap((colors) => {
                    this.myAPIService.getStyle(colors[index].id)
                        .subscribe(styleRef => {
                            if (styleRef) {
                                styleRef.colors.map(color => {
                                    refColors.push(color.colorId);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                })
                .forEach(refSize => {
                    refSize.headList.forEach(item => {
                        headList.push({
                            size: item.size,
                            value: 0
                        });
                    });
                })
                .forEach(val => {
                    initialcolors.push(val.color);
                })
                .forEach((row) => {
                    this.rowId += 1;
                    listRefRows.push(new rowValue(row.headList, initialcolors, this.rowId));
                })
                .value();

            const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ReferenceTableComponent);
            const ref = this.target.createComponent(factory);
            console.log(refColors.length)
            ref.instance.listRows = listRefRows;
            ref.instance.rowId = this.rowId;
            ref.instance.headList = _.uniqBy(headList, 'size');
            if (_.difference(refColors, initialcolors).length !== 0) {
                ref.instance.colors = _.difference(refColors, initialcolors);
                ref.instance.isAddRowValid = true;
            }
    });
  }
```

I have tries to put all the chain part in a New promise and in the then() I initiate my componant but my componant is initiated without data

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _(value)
                .chain()
                .tap((colors) => {
                    this.myAPIService.getStyle(colors[index].id)
                        .subscribe(styleRef => {
                            if (styleRef) {
                                styleRef.colors.map(color => {
                                    refColors.push(color.colorId);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                })
                .forEach(refSize => {
                    refSize.headList.forEach(item => {
                        headList.push({
                            size: item.size,
                            value: 0
                        });
                    });
                })
                .forEach(val => {
                    initialcolors.push(val.color);
                })
                .forEach((row) => {
                    this.rowId += 1;
                    listRefRows.push(new rowValue(row.headList, initialcolors, this.rowId));
                })
                .value();

})
  .then (() => {
     const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ReferenceTableComponent);
            const ref = this.target.createComponent(factory);
            console.log(refColors.length)
            ref.instance.listRows = listRefRows;
            ref.instance.rowId = this.rowId;
            ref.instance.headList = _.uniqBy(headList, 'size');
            if (_.difference(refColors, initialcolors).length !== 0) {
                ref.instance.colors = _.difference(refColors, initialcolors);
                ref.instance.isAddRowValid = true;
            }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by initiating my componant after the subscribe and using the tap() after the last forEach is executed like so:

```
                .tap((colors) => {
                this.myAPIService.getStyle(colors[index].id)
                    .subscribe(styleRef => {
                            if (styleRef) {
                                styleRef.colors.map(color => {
                                    refColors.push(color.colorId);
                                });
                            }
                        },
                            error => this.myNotificationService.error(`${error} !`, 'error'),
                        () => {
                            const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ReferenceTableComponent);
                            const ref = this.target.createComponent(factory);
                            ref.instance.listRows = listRefRows;
                            ref.instance.rowId = this.rowId;
                            ref.instance.headList = _.uniqBy(headList, 'size');
                            if (_.difference(refColors, initialcolors).length !== 0) {
                                ref.instance.colors = _.difference(refColors, initialcolors);
                            }
                        }
                    );
            })
```